# ios - making a slideshow effect (fade in/out and crossfade)

Tags: ios, image, video, fade, cross-fade

I am new on iOS; I am interested in making a slideshow by using videos or images. Following, I want to develop an application which can create a simple slideshow:

1/ Fade in fade out effect 
2/ [Crossfade effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNWNwnFfYx4)

## EDIT1:

After creating, I also want to save the slideshow to file like some video editor apps do.

Please let me know if there are any libraries which support those effect. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The [MTTransitions](https://github.com/alexiscn/MTTransitions) is your need,it includes 76 transitions,can use in image and video,if you want to export video that used transitions, you should use `AVAssetExportSession` in `AVFoundation` Framework,I hope it can help you

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
newView.alpha = 1;
[self.view addSubView:newView];

[UIView animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
   newView.alpha = 0;
   oldView.alpha = 1;
}, completion: (void (^)(BOOL finished)){
   [oldView removeFromSuperView];
})];
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I also want to save the effect to file. In that case, what should I do?

Comment: @LuongTruong, what do you mean 'save the effect to file'?

Comment: The flow should be like this: I choose 2 or 3 videos, add fade in, fade out, and crossfade in the end of each video. Then I save all videos with the effects to file (avi, mp4, and so on). Like some video editor apps do. :)

Comment: So you want to make a video editor... That a little to complicated to ask on SA. Anyhow, my answer is only relevant to the fade-in/out part of your question and for images only.